# save image file with a new name. In sandbox mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, save, rename, sandbox

Hello I am trying to save one image with different images sizes. I need it to rename each file with a new name Please look at my example. I work fine when it is not in sandbox mode. When sandbox mode is on it give me errors and will not work. This is ok give that apple has secured the file paths in sandbox. 
Mac osX 10.11
xCode 7.3

my code:

```
      problem-> {newFileNamePng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%ldx%ld).png",path,(long)sizeX,(long)sizeY];
    ---- end problem 
                pngData = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:options];
                BoolResult = [pngData writeToFile:newFileNamePng options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];


        if (!BoolResult) {
            NSLog(@"writeUsingSavePanel failed");
            NSLog(@"Write returned error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }//end if

}
```

I need to give a new name for each image saved. In sandbox mode. 
example:
filename(00x00).png,jpg,tiff,etc
rabbit(16x16).png
rabbit(120x120).png

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: newFileNamePng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%ldx%ld).png",path,(long)sizeX,(long)sizeY]; 
pngData = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:options];                                                                               BoolResult = [pngData writeToFile:newFileNamePng options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];